# If website user is logged in, then make object visible - if logged out, then invisible

Tags: javascript, object, authentication, visibility

This code to verify if the website user is logged in or not works perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (logged_in) {
        alert("My user is logged in!");
    } else {
        alert("My user is NOT logged in!");
    }
</script>
```

However, if instead of the Alert, I use this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (logged_in) {
        document.getElementById('txtLOGIN1').style.visibility='visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txtLOGIN1').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
</script>
```

It does not work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please? The 'txtLOGIN1' is a text box that I want to show or hide.

Comment: Any chance that it _is_ hidden, but just the same color as your background so it looks as if it is still there? Can you put your cursor in it and type? Either way, you have not provided enough information for us to be able to give you the answer. Please provide a [mcve]. If your first code works, just see if it also works with `if (true)` or `if (false)`. If that gives the same result you can leave out the PHP part from your question.

Comment: The CSS `visibility` property does not remove the element from the flow, it just makes it not visible. That means that the element will not be visible, but it will still be a part of the DOM, therefore taking visual space.

Comment: Ivar. Thanks. It is not hidden and not the same color as the background. Ful-stackz, I want it to take up the visual space while being able to toggle the visibility on and off.

Comment: @PhaedrusT.Wolfe Any errors in your browser's console? If I use that line of code here on SO and enter the ID of the answer box, it works just fine. So based on your information there is no way of telling what is going wrong.

Comment: Ivar. No errors. The fact its working fine for you tells me I have the general idea. I've no idea what information I am failing to send, so I guess I'll just have to keep playing with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your script placed in html? May be your dom element do not exist yet on the moment script fire?

try to use some thing like this:

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    if (logged_in) {
      document.getElementById('txtLOGIN1').style.visibility='visible';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('txtLOGIN1').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
```

Comment: Works Perfectly! Many Thanks.